# Sagemaker SDK on lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I'm getting the following message while running the Sagemaker SDK on my lambda function.
I have installed the correct libraries that are comparable with python 3.11 and the lambda.

The log data from lambda:

```
sagemaker.config INFO - Not applying SDK defaults from location: /etc/xdg/sagemaker/config.yaml
--
sagemaker.config INFO - Not applying SDK defaults from location: /home/sbx_user1051/.config/sagemaker/config.yaml
```

The log from the endpoint

```
2023-09-16T21:55:46,174 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Executing input_fn from inference.py ...
--
2023-09-16T21:55:46,174 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - Backend response time: 3557
2023-09-16T21:55:46,174 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Executing predict_fn from inference.py ...
2023-09-16T21:55:46,174 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Executing output_fn from inference.py ...
2023-09-16T21:55:46,174 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0 ACCESS_LOG - /127.0.0.1:35074 "POST /invocations HTTP/1.1" 200 3558
2023-09-16T21:55:46,174 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0 TS_METRICS - Requests2XX.Count:1\|#Level:Host\|#hostname:169.254.29.125,timestamp:1694901018
```

My code is

```
from sagemaker.pytorch.model import PyTorchModel, PyTorchPredictor 
from sagemaker.deserializers import JSONDeserializer
    
predictor = PyTorchPredictor(endpoint_name=ENDPOINT_NAME, deserializer=JSONDeserializer())
result = predictor.predict(decode)
```

The predictor function is what's breaking the run and sending the INFO level log

any thoughts on how to fix this?
I tried to look into documentation on what could fix this but did not find anything

i tried to work through, import different libraries and different levels of configs and still getting the error

Comment: I'm using Sagemaker Studio and was able to create Feature Store using Jupyter Notebook, few days back. Suddenly, I'm facing the same issue! Has AWS done any upgrade??
sagemaker.config INFO - Not applying SDK defaults from location: /etc/xdg/sagemaker/config.yaml
sagemaker.config INFO - Not applying SDK defaults from location: /root/.config/sagemaker/config.yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The info messages you are seeing is from [SDK defaults feature](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#configuring-and-using-defaults-with-the-sagemaker-python-sdk) that was added. It should have no impact to your code unless you are using that feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can quell this logging by setting the logging level to be less verbose. For example:

```
sagemaker_config_logger = logging.getLogger("sagemaker.config")
sagemaker_config_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```